# Can I replace a DDR2 RAM module with a DDR3 module?

Tags: memory, cpu, ddr3, ramdisk, ddr2

I am using desktop. here is the Configuration of motherboard.
Manufacturer    Simmtronics
Model   SM-IG31-MKII (CPU 1)
Version V1.0
Chipset Vendor  Intel
Chipset Model   P35/G33/G31
Chipset Revision    10
Southbridge Vendor  Intel
Southbridge Model   82801GB (ICH7/R)

Operating System
    Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
CPU
    Intel Pentium E5400 @ 2.70GHz   43 °C
    Wolfdale 45nm Technology
RAM
    2.00GB Single-Channel DDR2 @ 398MHz (6-6-6-18)
Motherboard
    Simmtronics SM-IG31-MKII (CPU 1)

I want to Upgrade my desktop With 4gb/8gb DDR3 RAM ? What Should I do IS it possible to Upgrade?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Comment: What type of memory: DDR2;  The maximum amount of memory your system supports is 8GB based on the chipset.  Since you failed to provided accurate information to identify the CPU, that is only an estimate, based on personal experience with older chipsets.  You also failed to identify the current amount of memory your system has.

Comment: none of the current DDRx slots are compatible with each other

Answer (score 2):

No. Slots for DDR2 and DDR3 are not compatible. Unless your board offers slots for both kinds of RAM and even than you might have to replace your CPU as modern CPUs usually contain the memory controller which, as far as I know, is also specific to a certain type of RAM.

Answer (score -1):

AMD's socket AM3 and AM3+ CPUs support both DDR2 and DDR3 however you would still have to have a motherboard that had both types of slots as they are not only incompatible voltage wise though also (intentionally) physically incompatible. Intel is *not* consumer friendly, they profit from the chips on every Intel socket motherboard and I've never heard of them making any effort to be consumer friendly.